# How to set conditions for plotting values from a 3rd column? Python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have imported data with pandas into 3 columns: DayOfYear, Field, Distance.

```
DayOfYear Field Distance
1          50      100
2          55      200
3          60      300
4          65      400
5          70      500
6          75      600
7          80      700
...
```

I want to plot Field against Distance but i want to do it for any range of the day of year that i choose. 
So instead of just plotting all the values of Distance and Field for all 365 days, 
I would like to plot them For say days 226-346. How should i go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) to performance a [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)  with [`DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
l1 = 226
l2 = 346
df[df['DayOfYear'].between(l1,l2)].set_index('Distance')['Field'].plot()
```

**Example for l1 = 2, l2 = 6,**

[image]

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html , `DataFrame.plot` use the index of DataFrame in the x axis, so we need set  `distance` like the` index`. please consider accept or upvote:)

Comment: you would need filter the datafraem by the hour with datetime series we have use `s.dt.hour.between(3,4)`